# In rig veda ,what is the whole story of Namuci and why was he killed by indra?

Tags: rig-veda, indra

Rig Veda 5.30.9

> स्त्रियो॒ हि दा॒स आयु॑धानि च॒क्रे किं मा॑ करन्नब॒ला अ॑स्य॒ सेना॑: । अ॒न्तर्ह्यख्य॑दु॒भे अ॑स्य॒ धेने॒ अथोप॒ प्रैद्यु॒धये॒ दस्यु॒मिन्द्र॑: ॥
> स्त्रियो हि दास आयुधानि चक्रे किं मा करन्नबला अस्य सेनाः । अन्तर्ह्यख्यदुभे अस्य धेने अथोप प्रैद्युधये दस्युमिन्द्रः ॥
>
> striyo hi dāsa āyudhāni cakre kim mā karann abalā asya senāḥ | antar hy akhyad ubhe asya dhene athopa praid yudhaye dasyum indraḥ ||
>
> English translation:
> “The slave (Namuci) made women his weapons what will his feminine le hosts do unto me? The two his best beloved, (Indra) confined in the inner apartments, and then went forth to combat against the Dasyus.”
>
> Commentary by Sāyaṇa: Ṛgveda-bhāṣya
> What will his feminine le hosts do unto me? Indra is supposed to say this; the two his best beloved: decapitation of Namuci by Indra is related in the gadā section of the Śalya parva of the Mahābhārata; Namuci through fear of Indra, took refuge in the solar rays; Indra promised that he would not harm him if he came forth, but broke his promise, and, on Namuci's issuing forth, cut off his head; by this he incurred the guilt of brahmanicide, for, Namuci was a brahman, but Indra was taught expiation of his sin by Brahmā.

What is the whole story of Namuci and why was he killed by Indra?